# Use shared database docker container in microservice architecture

Tags: linux, windows, docker, docker-compose, development-environment

From the count of questions tagged with `docker` i assume StackOverflow is the right place to ask (instead of e.g. [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docker)), if not, please point me to the right place or move this question accordingly.

My scenario is the following:

- multiple applications consisting of frontend (web GUI) and backend (REST services) are being developed following [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)/microservice approaches, each application has its own git repository
- some applications require a shared additional resource like frontend needs a HTTP server and multiple backend applications need a database server (with persistent storage)
- focus is primarily on offline mobile development (on the road) so a quick setup of required services/applications should be possible and the amount of resource overhead should be minimal. But of course the whole thing will be deployed/published at some point so i dont want to obstruct that if both can be managed
- development is done on windows and linux host machines
- access to all services from host machine is required for development purposes

What i am trying to achieve is to have a `docker-compose.yaml` file in the application repositories which i invoke via `docker-compose up` which would then start all required containers [if not running already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44731451), e.g. the database container is started when i invoke `docker-compose up` in a backend application repository.

My approach was to have a new git repository which defines all shared docker images/containers, with its own `docker-compose.yaml` where all devs would have to run `docker-compose build` whenever something changed (might be automated with a git commit hook in the future). The central `docker-compose.yaml` looks like this

```
version: "3"
services:

  postgres:
    build: ./images/postgres
    image: MY-postgres
    container_name: MY-postgres-server
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  httpd:
    build: ./images/httpd
    image: MY-httpd
    container_name: MY-httpd-server
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

The `Dockerfile` describing how each image is built is in its own subfolder and i think not relevant for the question, basically the default images for alpine + apache/postgres.

So the problem: how would a `docker-compose.yaml` in the application git repository look like that references the services/containers defined by the above central `docker-compose.yaml`.

Now since this [is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45915182/875020) [no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35597579/875020) [new](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43384538/875020) [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43426699/875020) [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35113957/875020), i did some research and honestly the variety of approaches and proposed solutions was confusing, for once the [various versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41013048/875020) and compatibilities, features that were deprecated, etc.

- We want one single database instance for now for performance reasons and simplicity ([reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/4rkq24/when_you_run_a_database_server_from_docker_do_you/)) or is this the problem because it is truly [considered an anti-pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html) (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41884241/875020)). Each application would be using its own database within the container, so no sync required on application level.
- I am reading about [volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598804/875020) or [data only](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/942) [containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414699/875020) to solve this problem, yet i cant understand how to implement
- [Some](https://forums.docker.com/t/single-db-instance-with-multiple-apps/40106/9) (Single Host scenario) suggest [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links) (with [`depends_on`](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/942)) while i think this concept has been superseeded by [networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks) but is it still applying? There [seemed to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034919/875020) an [`extends`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414699/875020) [option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33408244/875020) as well
- `docker-compose` has an option `--no-deps` which is described as `Don't start linked services.`. If i omit it, i would assume it does what i need, but here i think then problem is the difference in meaning of [image/container/service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35565770)
- Can a combination of [multiple compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) solve this problem? This would add a hard requirement on [project paths](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1647) though
- If i cant start the containers from my application directory, id like to at least link to them, is [`external_links`](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/942) the [right](https://blog.virtualzone.de/2016/09/docker-compose-link-containers-outside-compose-file-using-external_links.html) [approach](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3813#issuecomment-237549950)?
- There are some feature requests ([feature: including external docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/318), [allow sharing containers across services](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2075)) so maybe its just not possible currently with docker means? Then how to solve it with third-party like [dcao include](https://github.com/dnephin/compose-addons#dcao-include) (which doesnt support `version 3`)?

Wow, that escalated quickly. But i wanted to show the research i have done since i just cant believe that its currently not possible.

Comment: Please clarify what the actual question is. We have the context, general aim but no specific problem. Are you struggling with writing `docker-compose.yml` that works? Or are you wondering where to place this docker-compose file (separate repo vs copies in each microservice repo)? Or are you wondering about data persistence specifically? If it's the latter you need to bind-mount DB data dir into the container: `volumes`:
      `- ./db_data/lib/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql`
      `- ./db_data/log/postgresql:/var/log/postgresql`
      `- ./db_data/etc/postgresql:/etc/postgresql`

Comment: @szalski thanks for responding. i clarified a bit more what im struggling with, its the first. Volumes were only mentioned a couple of times in similar scenarios so i assumed they might be a possible solution yet i have absolutely no idea how.